# How to remove ERROR start-dfs.sh in Hadoop-3.2.0

Tags: hadoop, installation, hdfs, hadoop3

Getting following errors when running start-dfs.sh to start hadoop services:

```
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs namenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_NAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting datanodes
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs datanode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_DATANODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
Starting secondary namenodes [ahsan-Lenovo-G570]
ERROR: Attempting to operate on hdfs secondarynamenode as root
ERROR: but there is no HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER defined. Aborting operation.
```

Answer (score 0):

In hadoop home directory open etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh file and add below lines to remove error:

```
export HDFS_NAMENODE_USER=root
export HDFS_DATANODE_USER=root
export HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_USER=root
export YARN_RESOURCEMANAGER_USER=root
export YARN_NODEMANAGER_USER=root
```

You can add your user name by replacing root in above commands.

Comment: I have added these lines and now getting the following output:

Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: root@localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [ahsan-Lenovo-G570]
ahsan-Lenovo-G570: root@ahsan-lenovo-g570: Permission denied (publickey,password).

Comment: You need to create passwordless ssh authentication. Look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211848/hadoop-start-dfs-sh-permission-denied

Comment: I was making a mistake. I was doing all on root user. I have found https://blog.usejournal.com/hadoop-3-0-installation-on-ubuntu-18-04-step-by-step-pseudo-distributed-mode-2808f6b8e71f. 
This link creating a Hadoop group and user "hduser". In this way i have configured every thing very easily and in first attempt. 
Now i only missing javaws in ;my java file but my hadoop configured properly.
If I don't place javaws then what would be the bad?

Comment: Giving this error:
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/javaws doesn't exist

Comment: This maybe java setup problem as mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/568765/installing-java-8update-alternatives-error-alternative-path-usr-lib-jvm-jdk1