# hadoop Does not run properly

Tags: hadoop

I am new in hadoop and I run it by below steps:

```
ssh-keygen
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh localhost
./start-all.sh
```

but I get below error:

```
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as ... in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting datanodes
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting secondary namenodes [karbasi]
karbasi: Permission denied (publickey,password).
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
localhost: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Please help me in solving my problem.

Comment: Need to see you `start-all.sh` to get more detail.

Comment: What exactly is needed? i go to this path hadoop/sbin and run ./start-all.sh and  This command is a combination of start-dfs.sh, start-yarn.sh & mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh

Comment: i ran it by sudo (sudo ./start-all.sh ) .it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

[Permission denied issue at Hadoop Installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15211848/hadoop-start-dfs-sh-permission-denied)

In the above link, you can find the reason for the issue.

The issue occurs if any mistakes occur in ssh key generation or if the hadoop installation is not extracted by same user and started by the same user.